# Why are badges in Meta separate?

Tags: discussion, badges, meta

In Meta.TeX.SX, everyone's TeX.SX reputation is displayed.  However, the badges on Meta are separate from the badges on the main site.  Why is there the following inconsistency?

1. Reputation - Same on Meta and main site.  No reputation can be earned via Meta.
2. Badges - Separate for Meta and the main site.  Badges can be earned via Meta, but will only be shown in Meta.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The reputation is the same because the meta sites are not real Stack Exchange sites in their own right, but really just an attachment to the main sites. By having the same reputation all privileges are always equal on both and you don't have to work your way up again. Also, [voting has a different meaning on Meta](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#vote-differences).

The badges are separate, IMHO, to reflect your effort on Meta. Having some "Nice Question" or "Nice Answer" etc. badges here shows that you are interested in making the main site better. Also the "Enthusiast" or "Fanatic" badges show that you visit also Meta often. Having the same set of badges would not allow for this.